# Reset admin password on server JupyterHub

Tags: jupyter

I have root access to server with installed JupyterHub. How to reset admin password or add another admin for JupyterHub using root server access?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.